# Let A be a real symmetric matrix. Then there is a orthogonal matrix $N$ such that the matrix $D = N^{−1}AN = N^TAN$ is diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given the following theroem:

> Let $\rho: V → V$ be a symmetric operator (V is a vector space under $\mathbb{R}$). Then $\rho$ has a diagonal associated matrix.

Show that:

> Let A be a real symmetric matrix. Then there is a orthogonal matrix $N$ such that the matrix $D = N^{−1}AN = N^TAN$ is diagonal.

My try:

By the theorem, $A$ can be diagonalized. Now, let $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be the eigenvectors of $A$, then applying Gram-Schmidt an orthonormal basis $\{w_i\}_{i=1}^n$ we obtain  and we know that they are orthogonal. So let $N = (w_1 ... w_n)$.

But here I'm stuck because I don't know how to show $D = N^{−1}AN = N^TAN$ is diagonal.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix $N^\intercal AN$ is diagonal iff $N$ has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors of $A$ as columns, where $A$ has size $n \times n$. So we only have to show that the columns of $N$ form an orthonormal eigenbasis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

So let $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_r$ be the distinct eigenvalues of $A$ and $E_1, \dots, E_r$ be the corresponding eigenspaces. Then $\sum_{i = 1}^r \dim(E_i) = n$ by the theorem you stated at the top ($A$ is diagonalizable). Each $E_i$ has a basis and, as you already explained in your try, one can assume this basis to be orthogonal by Gram-Schmidt. Now if $i \neq j$, two vectors in $E_i$ and $E_j$ are always orthogonal (I assume that this is known here - eigenvectors to different eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix are orthogonal), so putting these eigenbases together yields an orthonormal set. But every orthonormal set is linearly independent, and since there are $n$ vectors, they must span $\mathbb{R}^n$.